# how to change the user right of windows using bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a `.bat` file to change user privileges so that I can make a admin account from guest account. I know it can happen from dos but the `net user` command is giving errors.

So please suggest how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for the following:

```
net localgroup administrators <user> /add
```